# Where is "domain-dir/applications/app-name" in glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I trying to dynamic reload in glassfish v4.0, and I got a problem.
I try to ["application-deployment-guide.pdf"](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf)(Page 56. To Reload Changes to Applications or Modules Dynamically) saying

> 1. Go to the root directory of the deployed application or module.
>      For an application:
>      domain-dir/applications/app-name
>      For an individually deployed module:
>      domain-dir/applications/module-name
> 2. Create or update the timestamp of the .reload file to load the changes.
>
> For UNIX: touch .reload
>   For Windows: echo> .reload
>
> If the .reload file doesn't exist, the touch or echo command creates it

And I checked "Reload", and saved 2 second at "Reload Poll Interval" in `[Glassfish Admin console > Domain > Applications Configuration]`.

Finally I restart glassfish server and deploy my application.

But dynamic reload is not working, even though modify `*.class` and input command `echo> .reload`

Now, I thought maybe I misunderstood about `domain-dir/applications/app-name` folder.

My glassfish home is `D:\Bin\glassfish4` and my application name is `WebApplication`.
Then `domain-dir/applications/app-name` is mean `D:\Bin\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\WebApplication\applications\WebApplication` isn't it?

Someone help me please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already suspected you have chosen the wrong path to your application....

The domains folder is this one: `glassfish4\glassfish\domains`

Inside of this folder there is a folder with the name of the domain you are actually using, by default this is `domain1`. This is the domain folder. Inside of this folder there is an `applications` folder and inside this one there should be your application.

I'm not sure but I guess it depends on wether it is a unix or a windows operating system but it may be that the `applications` folder contains a folder named `__internal` and this folder contains the applications...

To sum up: `glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\YOUR-APP`

Or: `glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\__internal\YOUR-APP`

You also have the possibility to look into your `domain.xml`. It will contain an entry for every deployed application containing the path where it is deploy. It looks like this:

```
<application context-root="/FirstWebService"
     location="file:/C:/.../NetBeansProjects/FirstWebService/build/web/" 
     directory-deployed="true" name="FirstWebService" object-type="user">
```

Comment: There in only "__internal" my application folder, It's right?

Comment: You're right~! My application directory is in the "NetbeansProjects" folder.  
Thank you so much